# Время работы программы очень длинное, возможна ли реализация з помощью хэш-таблиц?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, хеширование

Для программы используется список на 1млн чисел, нужно при складывании чисел x и y, то-есть A[i] и A[j] получить число s, которое лежит в диапазоне от -1000 до 1000, и найти количество уникальных чисел. Программа работает правильно, но проблема в длительности выполнения програми, которое достигает нескольки часов, возможно ли реализовать с помощью хэш-таблиц, чтобы сократить время работы?
Вот код

```
A = []
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        A.append(int(line))
n=len(A)
checker = []
s = A[0]+A[1]
checker.append(s)
print('Start')
for i in range(0, n-1):
    for j in range(1, n):
        if A[i]+A[j]>=-1000 and A[i]+A[j]<=1000:
            s = A[i]+A[j]
            if s not in checker:
                checker.append(s)
                print(checker)
del checker[0]
print('res:', len(checker))
print(checker)
print('End')
```

Comment: Почему такое условие: использовать хэш-таблицы? Может, как-то ещё можно?

Comment: Просто сделайте checker множеством (set) вместо списка (ну и добавление в множество через add вместо append).

Comment: Тут вообще по-другому решать надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот такой код:

100.000 записей где-то за 7 секунд перемалывает, 1000.000 за 2,5 минуты, но оптимизировать еще можно и наверное еще на порядок можно ускорить легко

его конечно надо допилить, но основные принципы более-менее тут раскрыты

1. исходный список сортируем по возрастанию
2. для каждого элемента списка определяем диапазон `left..right` сумма с числом из которого будет меньше 1000
3. поскольку список отсортирован, то бинарным поиском определяем индекс начиная с которого все числа больше `left` и индекс начиная с которого все числа меньше `right`
4. дальше (в идеале) нам надо просто занести в множество все числа по индексам `i_left..i_right`

я код писал на коленке, так что бинарный поиск немного недоработан :)
но есть куда расти - главное - **ПРИНЦИП**

код:

```
import random

count = 1000000

arr = [random.randint(-1000000, 1000000) for i in range(count)]

print("start")

arr.sort()

res = set()

for i in range(len(arr)):

    # определить границы диапазона
    left = -1000 - arr[i]
    right = 1000 - arr[i]

    # бинарным поиском найти граничные элементы
    border_l = 0
    border_r = len(arr) - 1

    pos_l = (border_r + border_l) // 2
    old = -1

    while True:
        value = arr[pos_l]

        if value < left:
            border_l = pos_l
        elif value > left:
            border_r = pos_l

        old = pos_l
        pos_l = (border_r + border_l) // 2

        if pos_l == old:
            break

    border_l = 0
    border_r = len(arr) - 1

    pos_r = (border_r + border_l) // 2
    old = -1

    while True:
        value = arr[pos_r]

        if value < left:
            border_r = pos_r
        elif value > left:
            border_l = pos_r

        old = pos_r
        pos_r = (border_r + border_l) // 2

        if pos_r == old:
            break


    for j in range(pos_l, pos_r + 1):

        value = arr[j]

        if value < left:
            continue

        if value > right:
            break

        res.add(arr[i] + arr[j])

print(len(res))
```

Comment: Если весь этот код (кроме `import`) поместить в функцию и задекорировать её в `numba.njit()`, то он выполняется вообще секунд за 8 (на миллионе записей, как в коде).

Answer (score 0):

> Программа работает правильно

правильно не значит оптимально :)

```
        if s not in checker:
            checker.append(s)
```

начнем с того, что раз вы каждый раз делаете поиск в checker, то он не должен быть списком, в котором поиск занимает O(n), делайте его сразу множеством, в котором поиск занимает O(log(n)) и не парьтесь с поиском - сразу добавляйте элемент в множество, а выведите элементы потом

```
checker = set()
...
checher.add(s)
```

далее, чем меньше условий - тем лучше

вместо

```
if A[i]+A[j]>=-1000 and A[i]+A[j]<=1000:
```

можно сделать

```
if (A[i] + A[j]) * (A[i] + A[j]) <= 1000000
```

если предварительно отсортировать список, то можно еще быстрее сделать

В общем надо просто полностью переписать код :)

Comment: `O(1)` же вроде у `set` в нормальных условиях. Вот если много коллизий, то до `O(n)` может доходить.

Comment: Какой смысл делить на два ответа?

Comment: @insolor, 2 кардинально разных подхода к решению задачи

Comment: @Zhihar, а, увидел, в том ответе через бинарную вставку/поиск. Но все равно, я бы делал одним ответом. Но это уже вам решать.